# pymongo aggregate - return count of each field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to do a group by in mongodb and I am using the pymongo interface.

Example of my data:

```
{
    "transmitters": [], 
    "receptors": [], 
    "text": "\"We have developed CellExcite, a sophisticated simulation environment for excitable-cell networks. CellExcite allows the user to sketch a tissue of excitable cells, plan the stimuli to be applied during simulation, and customize the diffusion model. CellExcite adopts Hybrid Automata (HA) as the computational model in order to efficiently capture both discrete and continuous excitable-cell behavior.\"", 
    "genes": [], 
    "simenvironment": [
        "CellExcite (web link to model)"
    ], 
    "channels": [], 
    "references": [
        112450
    ], 
    "modelconcepts": [
        "Spatio-temporal Activity Patterns", 
        "Simplified Models"
    ], 
    "celltypes": [
        "Heart cell", 
        "Squid axon"
    ], 
    "title": "CellExcite: an efficient simulation environment for excitable cells (Bartocci et al. 2008)", 
    "modeltype": [
        "Neuron or other electrically excitable cell"
    ], 
    "brainregions": [], 
    "_id": 112468
},
```

I want to get the number of models per cell type. As shown the model may have multiple cell types per model. How can I do this?

Here is my attempt:

```
pipeline = [{'$group' : {'_id' : '$celltypes', 'num_models' : {'$sum' : 1}}}, 
             {'$project': {'celltypes':1, 'num_models':1}}]
for doc in (models.aggregate(pipeline)):
    pprint (doc)
    break
```

Here is my result from this:

```
{u'_id': [u'Heart cell'], u'num_models': 6}
...snip...
{u'_id': [u'Heart cell', u'Squid axon'], u'num_models': 1}
```

I apologize for the output, I have many more models, and it is actually printing all of them.

Can anyone give me a hint as to where I may be wrong? All I want is a list of cell types and the number of models they are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, all you need to do is [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the celltypes because it is an array, so that you can group by each value separately:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$unwind': '$celltypes'},
    {'$group' : {
        '_id' : '$celltypes', 
        'num_models' : {'$sum' : 1}}
    }, 
    {'$project': {
        'celltypes':1,
        'num_models':1}
    }
]
```

Comment: you're a lifesaver